# TCP cannot detect closed socket in client

Tags: c, tcp

I have server that just connects to a client and right after that disconnects, while client tries to send an integer to a closed socket (scanf is to ensure server closese it first). I use send with MSG_NOSIGNAL and check for EPIPE but the flag is not set. I think result should have printed value of -1, or 0, but it is equal to 1, because I am writing on already closed socket. Can someone explain that?

Server Code:

```
#define QUEUE_LENGTH     5
#define PORT_NUM     10002
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock, msg_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    socklen_t client_address_len;

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // creating IPv4 TCP socket
    if (sock < 0)
        syserr("socket");

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(
            INADDR_ANY); // listening on all interfaces
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM); 

    // bind the socket to a concrete address
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address,
             sizeof(server_address)) < 0)
        syserr("bind");

    // switch to listening (passive open)
    if (listen(sock, QUEUE_LENGTH) < 0)
        syserr("listen");

    printf("accepting client connections on port %hu\n",
           ntohs(server_address.sin_port));


    for (;;) {
        client_address_len = sizeof(client_address);
        msg_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address,
                          &client_address_len);
        if (msg_sock < 0)
            syserr("accept");



        printf("ending connection\n");
        if (close(msg_sock) < 0) {
            printf("ErrorClosingSocket\n");
            break;
        }
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
int sendSomething(void *to_send, int socket, uint32_t length) {

    if (send(socket, to_send, length, MSG_NOSIGNAL) !=
        length) {
        if (errno == EPIPE)  // Sending on closed connection
            return 0;
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct addrinfo addr_hints;
    struct addrinfo *addr_result;

    int err;

    if (argc != 3)
        fatal("Usage: %s host port\n", argv[0]);

    // 'converting' host/port in string to struct addrinfo
    memset(&addr_hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    addr_hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    addr_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    addr_hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    // argv[1] is localhost and argv[2] is 10002 
    err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &addr_hints, &addr_result);
    if (err == EAI_SYSTEM) // system error
        syserr("getaddrinfo: %s", gai_strerror(err));
    else if (err != 0) // other error (host not found, etc.)
        fatal("getaddrinfo: %s", gai_strerror(err));


    // initialize socket according to getaddrinfo results
    sock = socket(addr_result->ai_family, addr_result->ai_socktype,
                  addr_result->ai_protocol);
    if (sock < 0)
        syserr("socket");

    // connect socket to the server
    if (connect(sock, addr_result->ai_addr, addr_result->ai_addrlen) < 0)
        syserr("connect");

    freeaddrinfo(addr_result);


    int result;
    scanf("%d", &result);
    uint16_t test;

    test = htons(1);
    result = sendSomething(&test, sock, sizeof(test));
    printf("result:%d\n", result);

    if (close(sock) < 0) {
        printf("ErrorClosingSocket\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: Fatal and Syserr are just for reporting errors

Comment: did you only try with localhost or did you try with a real remote box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way TCP works. When the server closes the socket, then a FIN is sent to the client. This *only* signals, that the *server* will not send any more data. It does not necessarily mean, that it does not want to *receive* more data.

Thus, the client can call `send()` on the socket without the OS reporting an error. If the server indeed closed the whole socket, then it will send a **TCP reset packet** as a response to incoming data indicating that condition. Now, future operations on the socket (write/close) will indicate an error.

It is indeed possible for the server (or any peer) to only shutdown the connection half-way (the reading or the writing side) with the syscall `shutdown()`. If the server shuts down the connection for writing, the same thing happens on the network as if the server closed the whole connection with `close()`. It is the duty of a higher level protocol to determine, when a connection should be closed for each side.

If you want to make sure, that all data that you sent was indeed acknowledged by the peer, you can use the `SO_LINGER` socket option. But a more common way is, to make this sure as a part of the communication protocol, i.e. one part requests to shutdown the connection on a higher level (for example, the smtp `QUIT` command) and the peer reacts on it by closing the tcp connection.

Comment: But what can client do to determine if the data send were indeed received by the server, because in my case client doesn't know that. The other question is, do I understand correctly that client can get an error of reading fom closed socket in two ways: from two writes (error on the second) from the client side, or one client read?

Comment: @mikol You should take a look at the `SO_LINGER` option if you want to make sure, that all data was received by the peer.